# Rotating Image on Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

In my web app I am allowing users to choose images. If the height of the image is greater than the width then I rotate the image by 270 degrees.

I am confuse about what should be the ideal size for the rotated image as I would be saving that rotated image later on.

For example if a user upload a image with low resolution what should be the size there and what if the user uploads an image with a high revolution what would be the size than?

I don't want the pixels to be distorted. Any good library to rotate image on the client side? Or any algorithm which can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the naive canvas approach like this:

Basically you'll be drawing the image on a canvas, rotated, then saving the canvas to a dataUrl

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
//save the context
//pushes a Matrix on the transformation stack
context.save();
context.translate(x, y); //where to put image (in the canvas)
context.rotate(angle); //angle in degrees (i think...)
context.scale(scale); //optional scale
//rotate around center of image
context.drawImage(bitmap, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2);
//or rotate around top left corner of image
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
//restore the canvas
//pop a matrix off the transformation stack
context.restore();
//now save the canvas to a data url for download or to display in an image object / tag
var data = canvas.toDataUrl();
```

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement

http://html5.litten.com/understanding-save-and-restore-for-the-canvas-context/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Blob` object approach. Convert the image to blob objects and you can play with it. I cant help with code coz am not much aware of blobs. Please do more research on blobs and you can achieve what you want to do using Blobs.